# Scheme - Return a list of pairs from 2 given lists

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm working on this procedure which is supposed to return a list of pairs from 2 given lists. So for example (pairs '(1 2 3) '(a b c)) should return **'((1.a) (2.b) (3.c))**.

This is my logic so far. I would take the first element of each list and recursively call the procedure again with cdr as the new arguments. My result is returning a list such as this: **(1 a 2 b 3 c)**

Where is my logic going wrong? I know there is a list missing somewhere, but I'm not an expert at Scheme.

Any suggestions?

```
   (define pairs
      (lambda (x y)
        (if (or (null? x) (null? y))
          '()
          (cons (car x)
            (cons (car y)
                (pairs (cdr x)(cdr y)))))))

    (pairs '(1 2 3) '(a b c))
```

Comment: @Oscar: I reopened since he asked about the specific flaw in this attempt - rather than asking for full solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you're looking for should look like this:

```
((1 a) (2 b) (3 c))
```

In reality this structure is similar to this:

```
(cons
   (cons 1 a)
   (cons
      (cons 2 b)
      (cons
        (cons 3 c)
        '()
      )
    )
 )
```

So what you're looking for is to append pairs to a list instead of adding all items to the list like you do. Simply your result looks like this:

```
(1 (2 (pairs ...)))
```

Your code should look like this:

```
(define pairs
  (lambda (x y)
    (if (or (null? x) (null? y))
      '()
      (cons
        (cons (car x) (car y))
        (pairs (cdr x) (cdr y))))))
```

This code might work, but it isn't perfect. We could make the code pass the list we create as a third parameter to make the function tail recursive.

You'd have something like this:

```
(define pairs
  (lambda (x y)
    (let next ((x x) (y y) (lst '()))
      (if (or (null? x) (null? y))
        (reverse lst)
        (next (cdr x)
              (cdr y)
              (cons
                (cons (car x) (car y)) 
                lst))))))
```

As you can see, here since we're adding next element at the beginning of the list, we have to reverse the `lst` at the end. The difference here is that every time `next` is called, there is no need to keep each state of x and y in memory. When the named let will return, it won't be necessary to pop all the values back to where it called. It will simply return the reversed list.

That said, instead of using `reverse` we could simply return `lst` and use `(append lst (cons (car x) (car y)))` which would append the pair at the end of the list... Since lists are linked lists... in order to append something at the end of the list, scheme has to walk over all list items... which migth not be good with big list. So the solution is to add everything and at the end reorder the list as you wish. The reverse operation would happen only once.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that you produce a value that prints as `(1 . 3)` by evaluating `(cons 1 3)`. However in your program you are doing `(cons 1 (cons 3 ...))` which will prepend 1 and 3 to the following list.

In other words: Instead of `(cons (car x) (cons (car y)   (pairs ...))`
use `(cons (cons (car x) (car y)   (pairs ...))`.

Answer (score 3):

Using `map` simplifies it a lot:

```
(define (pairs x y)
  (map (λ (i j) (list i j)) x y))
```

Testing:

```
(pairs '(1 2 3) '(a b c))
```

Output:

```
'((1 a) (2 b) (3 c))
```